custom mount type is not reconized on cypress component test
i'm using react 18.2, node 20.10 and cypress 13.2.0
i've updated my mount type like this to use redux in my component tests
import { EnhancedStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { MountOptions, MountReturn } from 'cypress/react18';
import { RootState } from './src/App/store';

// Augment the Cypress namespace to include type definitions for
// your custom command.
// Alternatively, can be defined in cypress/support/component.d.ts
// with a <reference path="./component" /> at the top of your spec.
declare global {
  namespace Cypress {
    interface Chainable {
      /**
       * Mounts a React node
       * @param component React Node to mount
       * @param options Additional options to pass into mount
       */
      mount(
        component: React.ReactNode,
        options?: MountOptions & { reduxStore?: EnhancedStore<RootState> }
      ): Cypress.Chainable<MountReturn>;
    }
  }
}

my cypress custom command file is named commands.tsx
mount function is overrided like this :
import { mount } from 'cypress/react18';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from '../../src/App/store';

Cypress.Commands.add('mount', (component, options = {}) => {
  const { reduxStore = store } = options;
  const {} = options;

  const wrapped = <Provider store={reduxStore}>{component}</Provider>;

  return mount(wrapped, options);
});

but reduxStore option property is not reconized, option definition is not overrided. I think is only a typescript error but i don't know where
here the tsconfig definitions
into cypress folder
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["es5", "dom"],
    "types": ["cypress", "node"],
    "jsx": "preserve"
  },
  "include": ["**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx", "../cypress.d.ts"]
}

and into root folder :
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2021",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "es2021"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmitOnError": false,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "module": "esnext"
  },
  "include": ["src", "@types", "build/dvf.d.ts", "type.d.ts", "cypress.d.ts"]
}

if i write the type definition directly in command file, no error, but the test crash because no react-redux found
